# texture not showing in eevee render

Tags: texturing

I connected noise texture to the roughness of the sphere. and then when i did the same for another object its not showing in EEVEE. but in cycles its working. In EEVEE when I tried to change the size of noise texture the material is just flickering and not showing the noise pattern.same case with voronoi, brick textures, etc. I encountered with this problem today. till yesterday it was working fine.

Same problem occurs when I connect the noise texture to the bump, base color, etc. the texture is appearing only on the very first object placed on the viewport. for the objects placed after the first is not showing textures in EEVEE. in the image both spheres have same texture, but the voronoi texture is only visible on the sphere on which the material is applied first.

[image: both spheres have same texture. but the voronoi texture is only visible on the sphere on which the material is applied first]

Comment: May be they have different UVMaps.